# HAProxy : Replace rsprep directive by http-response replace-header

Tags: haproxy

I inherited a haproxy server that was running the version 1.8.  Upgraded it to version 2.1.  Haproxy wouldn't restart.  Found in the log that the issue was with this line in the configuration file:

```
rsprep ^Set-Cookie:\ (.*) Set-Cookie:\ \1;\ Secure
```

The error was

> The 'rsprep' directive is not supported anymore since HAProxy 2.1. Use
>   'http-response replace-header' instead

Removed `rsprep` and it worked.  But I am now curious to know what impact it may have.  How do I replace the above configuration using `http-response replace-header`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it's adding the word `Secure` to the Cookie header value. It's doing a regex, capturing everything as group 1, then referencing group 1 and adding Secure to the end. Per [docs](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#4-rsprep).

Using replace header:

```
http-response replace-header Set-Cookie (.*) \1;\ Secure
```

There are more examples in the docs [here](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.1/configuration.html#4.2-http-response%20replace-header)